# Input mismatch when reading double from file

Tags: java, text-files, inputmismatchexception

I have to write a program that will read the names and balances from text file "balances.txt" and organize into a report that will then sum up the balances into a total. This is what the file contains:

```
JAKIE JOHNSON,2051.59
SAMUEL PAUL SMITH,10842.23
ELISE ELLISON,720.54
```

I had originally written the code which gave me exactly what I wanted, but was told not use loops, arrays, or `parseDouble`. I've now tried the following, but I keep getting an error every time I used `nextDouble`. The code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.io.FileInputStream ;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException ;
import java.io.IOException ;
import java.util.Scanner ;

public class BankFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner fileIn = null;

        try {
            String filename = "balances.txt" ; 
            File newFile = new File(filename);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(newFile);

            in.useDelimiter(",");

            String name = in.next();
            System.out.println(name);
            // trying to see if first name will display

            double money = in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(money);
            // trying to see if first double will display
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output and exception stacktrace:

```
JAKIE JOHNSON
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at Lab2.main(BankFile.java:52) `
```

Comment: Do `next`, `next`, then `nextDouble` to advance the Scanner and receive the correct input.

Comment: we need to see the code that don't work, not the code that does work

Comment: sorry, I had forgotten to add the code I was struggling with

Comment: @Derek you are using delimiter , so it gets the wrong input

Comment: @Derek `useDelimiter` will return a new Scanner Object to use

Comment: @AndrewL. What do you mean?

Comment: @ScaryWombat The delimiter won't catch the newline thus will go to the next line, giving an invalid double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)):

> **`useDelimiter`**
>
> `public Scanner useDelimiter(String pattern)`
>
> Sets this scanner's delimiting pattern to a pattern constructed from the specified String.

Now if you take a look at how you do yours:

```
in.useDelimiter(",");
```

This will use commas as the delimiter, now let's take a look at your text file:

```
JAKIE JOHNSON,2051.59
SAMUEL PAUL SMITH,10842.23
ELISE ELLISON,720.54
```

At first it may seem that commas are fine, but since you've set the delimiter, this is what happens:

First you call `in.next()` which returns:

```
JAKIE JOHNSON,2051.59
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That's fine, but when you then call `in.nextDouble()`, the below happens:

```
JAKIE JOHNSON,2051.59
              ^^^^^^^
SAMUEL PAUL SMITH,10842.23
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As you can see, the next line is also selected along with the double, which isn't a valid double. This causes Java to report an `InputMismatchException`, as the expected input isn't what you get - a string. To combat this, use a regular expression to also delimit newlines:

```
in.useDelimiter(",|\n");
```

This will match new-lines *and* commas, so it will delimit correctly. The pipe (`|`) means that it will delimit *either*. This will correctly output:

```
JAKIE JOHNSON
2051.59
```

Comment: The `useDelimiter` method returns a `Scanner` object,  Doesn't this need to be used?

Comment: I don't believe so @ScaryWombat.